# SourceTree git: how to specify default non-standard push branch?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have atlassian SourceTree git client. When I attempt to push, the default remote branch is master.

How I can setup the client so default branch is something else than 'master' (such as 'refs/for/master') ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Each of your branches can have a different upstream branch, so you'll need to set them up separately for each one.  However:

```
# git push --set-upstream remotename remotebranch
```

Will let you set your current branches upstream to the given remotename/remotebranch combo.

Comment: I need to do that for  SourceTree UI

Answer (score 0):

Repository -> Repository Settings
Click [Edit Config File...]

In the config file:

In this section:
[remote "origin"]

Add the following line:
    push = refs/heads/*:refs/for/*